# C# Referring to the current form through a static method

Tags: c#, winforms, static, scope, encapsulation

I'm working on a method that is static, and returns a value off a WinForm, it spawns the new form on a button click, and upon hitting the submit or cancel buttons it throws back its value.

The issue is, I cant refer to a combobox control on my form to populate it with the results of my sqlreader.

I have read suggestions that I use a wrapper that looks akin to

```
public ComboBox comboHolder { get return this.foo }
```

however I can't seem to refer to it either. Any suggestions to remedy this ?

Full code

```
        public ComboBox comboboxWrapper
    {
        get { return this.comboUsernames; }
    }
    public static string SelectProfile()
    {

        Form selectProfile = new Select_Profile();
        selectProfile.ShowDialog();

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Users.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SelectAllUsers", connection);
        SqlDataReader usersReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        List<string> accountNames = new List<string>();

        while (usersReader.Read())
        {
            accountNames.Add((string)usersReader["Username"]);
        }

        //populate the combo box

        foreach (string s in accountNames)
        {
           //I'd like to call comboboxWrapper here.

        }
        //set the combo box to have a default item
       // combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Also, this is a work in progress, I realize I should have some try, catch and a finally statement, other than that i'm open to any suggestions for code improvement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just not making the method static.  But if you really need to for some reason, you could pass a reference to the form into your static method, e.g.:

```
SelectProfile(Form myForm)
```

Then you would be able to use it inside the method like this:

```
foreach (string s in accountNames)
{
   // e.g myForm.comboboxWrapper
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your static method need object of class for that you have to pass object of class where comboboxwrapper defined

```
public static string SelectProfile(ClassobjectofCoboboxWrapper obj)
{
    obj.comboboxWrapper;
}
```

Call to this method from outside

```
SelectProfile(new ClassobjectofCoboboxWrapper())
```

Note:
As static method are not related to instace of object its related to class. So to refer element in static method which are not static you either need to create object of refering class or you need to pass object of class your want to refer.

Answer (score 0):

This is your form instance:

```
Form selectProfile = new Select_Profile();
```

So you'd call `comboboxWrapper` on that instance:

```
selectProfile.comboboxWrapper
```

Though first you'll need to change its type, since `Form` doesn't have a member called `comboboxWrapper`.  Declare it like this instead:

```
Select_Profile selectProfile = new Select_Profile();
```

or simply:

```
var selectProfile = new Select_Profile();
```

Even though the `comboboxWrapper` member is defined outside the `static` method, it's *inside* the form instance.  A `static` member has no default notion of a particular instance and needs to be provided with one.  Or, in this case, internally creates one.

Answer (score 0):

First, *decompose* your solution: just don't *cram* database and UI into single method. Next think over what your method is *supposed to return* as a `String`:

```
public static IEnumerable<String> AccountNames() {
  //TODO: Move it into Settings/Config... 
  String connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Users.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

  // Dispose (via using) all Disposable...  
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();

    // Dispose: prevent resource leakage...
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SelectAllUsers", connection)) {
      using (SqlDataReader usersReader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        while (usersReader.Read())
          yield return (string)usersReader["Username"];
      }
    } 
  }
}

// returns selected profile 
// or null if no profile was seelcted
public static string SelectProfile() {
  // var: You need Select_Profile, not just a Form, right?
  // again (using): don't forget to clear up the resources
  using (var selectProfile = new Select_Profile()) {
    // Providing that comboboxWrapper is public (bad practice) 
    // or SelectProfile() is implemented within Select_Profile class (good   one) 
    selectProfile.comboboxWrapper.Items.AddRange(AccountNames());

    if (selectProfile.comboboxWrapper.Items.Count > 0)
      selectProfile.comboboxWrapper.SelectedIndex = 0;

    if (selectProfile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
      if (selectProfile.comboboxWrapper.SelectedIndex < 0)
        return null; // No item to select
      else
        selectProfile.comboboxWrapper.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
    else 
      return null; // Just closed
  }
}
```